# Does Tox get along with catkin's setup.py?

Tags: ros, python, catkin, python2.7, setup.py

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to automate the testing of my package using [Tox](https://testrun.org/tox/latest/) but not without problems. It seems that Tox doesn't like catkin's `setup.py` config file, at least the barebones `setup.py`  from [catkin's documentation](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html).

Here's my `tox.ini` config file:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27, py34

[testenv]
deps =
    catkin_pkg
    rospkg
    coverage
    flake8
    coveralls
    nose
    nose-cov
    nose-cover3
commands = nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=rospy_utils
```

It basically tries to execute the tests in a Python 2.7 and 3.4 environments so
And here's my `setup.py`file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

d = generate_distutils_setup(
    # #  don't do this unless you want a globally visible script
    # scripts=['bin/myscript'],
    packages=['rospy_utils'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'}
)

setup(**d)
```

Both seem ok but, when I run `tox`on my package root folder I get the following trace from tox:

```
viki@vROS:[~/devel/mona...src/rospy_utils]$ tox
GLOB sdist-make: /home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/src/rospy_utils/setup.py
py27 inst-nodeps: /home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/src/rospy_utils/.tox/dist/rospy_utils-0.2.0.zip
ERROR: invocation failed (exit code 1), logfile: /home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/src/rospy_utils/.tox/py27/log/py27-4.log
ERROR: actionid=py27
msg=installpkg
cmdargs=[local('/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/src/rospy_utils/.tox/py27/bin/pip'), 'install', '--pre', '-U', '--no-deps', '/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/src/rospy_utils/.tox/dist/rospy_utils-0.2.0.zip']
env={'ROS_MAVEN_REPOSITORY': 'https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/raw/master', 'ROS_DISTRO': 'hydro', 'GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID': 'this-is-deprecated', 'PYTHONHASHSEED': '1092722124', 'LASR_INSTALL_PATH': '/opt/Loquendo/LASR', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', 'XDG_SEAT_PATH': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0', 'ROS_MAVEN_DEPLOYMENT_REPOSITORY': '/home/viki/devel/rosbuild_ws/devel/share/maven', 'CPATH': '/home/viki/devel/rosbuild_ws/devel/include:/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/devel/include:/home/viki/devel/catkin_ws/devel/include:/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/devel/include:/opt/ros/hydro/include', 'LOGNAME': 'viki', 'USER': 'viki', 'PATH': '/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/src/rospy_utils/.tox/py27/bin:/home/viki/devel/rosbuild_ws/devel/bin:/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/devel/bin:/home/viki/devel/catkin_ws/devel/bin:/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/devel/bin:/opt/ros/hydro/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games', 'GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL': '/tmp/keyring-RJVCk2', 'CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH': '/home/viki/devel/rosbuild_ws/devel:/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/devel:/home/viki/devel/catkin_ws/devel:/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/devel:/opt/ros/hydro', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/home/viki/devel/rosbuild_ws/devel/lib:/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/home/viki/devel/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/devel/lib:/opt/ros/hydro/lib', 'SSH_AGENT_PID': '2442', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'xterm', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'XDG_SESSION_PATH': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0', 'XDG_SESSION_COOKIE': 'cf0fccd607b7ba15bad9beb400000011-1420981571.218005-898442704', 'SESSION_MANAGER': 'local/vROS:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2203,unix/vROS:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2203', 'SHLVL': '1', 'MANDATORY_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu-2d.mandatory.path', 'DISPLAY': ':0', 'WINDOWID': '67108869', 'LTTS7_DEFAULTSESSION': '/opt/Loquendo/LTTS7/bin/default.session', 'LTTS_INSTALL_PATH': '/opt/Loquendo/LTTS7', 'ROS_MASTER_URI': 'http://localhost:11311', 'GPG_AGENT_INFO': '/tmp/keyring-RJVCk2/gpg:0:1', 'HOME': '/home/viki', 'PYTHONPATH': '/home/viki/devel/rosbuild_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/viki/devel/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/tmp/keyring-RJVCk2/ssh', 'ROS_MAVEN_PATH': '/home/viki/devel/rosbuild_ws/devel/share/maven:/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/devel/share/maven:/opt/ros/hydro/share/maven', 'VIRTUAL_ENV': '/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/src/rospy_utils/.tox/py27', 'ROS_ROOT': '/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros', 'GDMSESSION': 'ubuntu-2d', 'DEFAULTS_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu-2d.default.path', 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH': '/home/viki/devel/rosbuild_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/home/viki/devel/catkin_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/pkgconfig', 'ROS_PACKAGE_PATH': '/home/viki/devel/rosbuild_ws/src:/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks', 'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP': 'Unity', 'ROS_TEST_RESULTS_DIR': '/home/viki/devel/rosbuild_ws/build/test_results', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS': 'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-HiOgLA6ZII,guid=1587a65cd6dd93256efa7fc1000000ac', '_': '/usr/local/bin/tox', 'XAUTHORITY': '/home/viki/.Xauthority', 'CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR': '/home/viki/devel/rosbuild_ws/build/test_results', 'DESKTOP_SESSION': 'ubuntu-2d', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'XDG_CONFIG_DIRS': '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu-2d:/etc/xdg', 'UBUNTU_MENUPROXY': 'libappmenu.so', 'OLDPWD': '/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws', 'ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES': '/home/viki/devel/rosbuild_ws/devel/share/common-lisp:/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/share/ubuntu-2d:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/', 'PWD': '/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/src/rospy_utils', 'ROS_ETC_DIR': '/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros', 'COLORTERM': 'gnome-terminal', 'ROS_WORKSPACE': '/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws', 'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'}
Processing ./.tox/dist/rospy_utils-0.2.0.zip
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-_0YxRt-build/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        package_dir={'': 'src'}
      File "/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/src/rospy_utils/.tox/py27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_pkg/python_setup.py", line 76, in generate_distutils_setup
        package = parse_package(package_xml_path)
      File "/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/src/rospy_utils/.tox/py27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 356, in parse_package
        raise IOError('Path "%s" is neither a directory containing a "%s" file nor a file' % (path, PACKAGE_MANIFEST_FILENAME))
    IOError: Path "." is neither a directory containing a "package.xml" file nor a file
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
    
      File "/tmp/pip-_0YxRt-build/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    
        package_dir={'': 'src'}
    
      File "/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/src/rospy_utils/.tox/py27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_pkg/python_setup.py", line 76, in generate_distutils_setup
    
        package = parse_package(package_xml_path)
    
      File "/home/viki/devel/monarch/code/trunk/catkin_ws/src/rospy_utils/.tox/py27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 356, in parse_package
    
        raise IOError('Path "%s" is neither a directory containing a "%s" file nor a file' % (path, PACKAGE_MANIFEST_FILENAME))
    
    IOError: Path "." is neither a directory containing a "package.xml" file nor a file
    
    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-_0YxRt-build
```

It seems that line 10 of `setup.py` lacks of some parameter that Tox wants but I am yet not very handy neither with `setup.py` nor `tox`. I've looked for some info both in the ros wiki and here in answers.ros.org and I did not find anything that could help me work out the problem (In fact, I believe that this is the first `tox`related question).

Any hints here? Has anybody used tox before in ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201644/does-tox-get-along-with-catkin%27s-setup.py?/) by [Victor Gonzalez-Pacheco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2660/victor-gonzalez-pacheco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2015-01-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**EDIT:**

I've found a cleaner way to solve it.

Ideally `setup.py` and `package.xml` should be in the same dir. However, this does not happens inside a `tox` venv unless you tell it what files should be included. To do so [you need to create a `MANIFEST.in`](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#the-manifest-in-template) in the same dir as `setup.py` and list there all the files you want to include in your source distribution.
Here is what I put in my `MANIFEST.in`:

```
include package.xml
```

And my `setup.py` now is the barebones `setup.py` listed in the [Catkin documentation](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html):

```
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

d = generate_distutils_setup(
    # #  don't do this unless you want a globally visible script
    # scripts=['bin/myscript'],
    packages=['rospy_utils'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'}
)

adminstrosetup(**d)
```

It seems that every ROS-related file that you don't include in the `MANIFEST.in` won't be included in the source distribution that is put into the `tox` virtual env. I guess that, if you need to do some rostests, use some ROS msgs, etc., you might need to include them here as well.

---

**Just for future reference, I leave the old answer here:**

As @William points out, it seems that the `generate_distutils_setup` included in the `setup.py` needs to know the location of the `package.xml` file. The call has [an optional parameter that defaults to `os.path.curdir`](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg/blob/master/src/catkin_pkg/python_setup.py#L46) which is usually ok since `setup.py` is included in the same dir as `package.xml`.

However, it seems that `tox` runs the `setup.py` in a virtual environment located in `/tmp/`. Therefore, if you don't tell `generate_distutils_setup` that you are running in a separate dir it will fail.

I've modified my `setup.py`  to tell it where to find the real path of the `package.xml` file and now I can run my `tox` commands perfectly. That's how my `setup.py` looks like now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

import rospkg
THIS_PKG = 'rospy_utils'
rospack = rospkg.RosPack()
pkg_path = rospack.get_path(THIS_PKG)

d = generate_distutils_setup(
    # #  don't do this unless you want a globally visible script
    # scripts=['bin/myscript'],
    packages=['rospy_utils'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    package_xml_path=pkg_path
)

adminstrosetup(**d)
```

---

Originally posted by [Victor Gonzalez-Pacheco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2660/victor-gonzalez-pacheco/) with karma: 396 on 2015-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-24**:
Another option would be to assume that the `package.xml` and the `setup.py` are always next to each other (a pretty safe bet) and use the directory containing the `setup.py` as the `package.xml` path rather than using `rospkg` to find it. `rospkg` will require the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` to be set.

**Comment by [Victor Gonzalez-Pacheco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2660/victor-gonzalez-pacheco/) on 2015-01-25**:
Yes, you are right. The problem was that `tox` did not include the `package.xml` file. I've updated my answer with a cleaner solution.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2018-03-08**:
What is "adminstrosetup"?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yeah, unfortunately the `setup.py` while trying to be conventional, in practice that `setup.py` is sort of a crutch we use to get Python code to install to the correct place. Rather then trying to figure out where your Python code should go on every different system and variation we rely on the setuptools infrastructure to give us the right answer.

Obviously this is not working for you out of the box, but looking at the error it seems mostly confused about where the `package.xml` is. You might be able to modify your `setup.py` to make this work by changing to the directory of the `setup.py`before running the `generate_distutils_setup` function. At best I would call this a hack.

I don't really have any experience with `tox`, but my understanding is that many people use it to install into a virtualenv for several versions of Python before doing testing in each. It should be possible to install catkin packages into a virtualenv, but I haven't tried that lately. Unfortunately at this point I wouldn't know how to proceed with integrating `tox` into this workflow.

Here are some links which might help you to decide what to look at next:

- This is a script that catkin runs to extract information from the `setup.py`: https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/indigo-devel/cmake/interrogate_setup_dot_py.py
- This is the CMake code which handles installing Python code: https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/indigo-devel/cmake/catkin_python_setup.cmake

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-01-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor Gonzalez-Pacheco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2660/victor-gonzalez-pacheco/) on 2015-01-24**:
Thanks @William, you have pointed me to the right direction.
Indeed, it seems that `generate_distutils_setup` needs to know where is the `package.xml` dir. If you don't tell it, he'll look for it in `os.curdir()` and fail since we are in a `venv`.
In a while I'll post an answer with the details